# window open not working

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get my input text value to become part of the window open link.

Here's my code:

```
window.open('./modul/mod_input.php?idpo='+
            document.getElementById('idpo').value+'',
            'Window1',
            'menubar=no,width=540,height=360,toolbar=no');
```

But it doesn't work. But when I try use this code it work

```
window.open('./modul/mod_input.php?idpo=',
            'Window1',
            'menubar=no,width=540,height=360,toolbar=no');
```

So I think the problem was at `getElementById`

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: Hey i already solved this problem by myself,.. sorry for asking.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that there is no element with the id `idpo` in the document, therefore, trying to access its `value` throws an error. Make sure that such an element exists.

As a side note, though entirely unrelated to your issue, `.value+''` could be replaced with `.value`. Appending an empty string does not alter the final string, which is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any element with an `id` of `idpo`? If not, this code wouldn't even execute. You can check firefox's firebug's console, or chrome's developer tools to check what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap as David sayed  - make sure that the element exists.

you can check it by adding:

```
var element =  document.getElementById('idpo');
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
{
    alert("Element exists");
}
else {
    alert("Does not exist");
}
```